# Yelp API HTTP Request Authorization Bearer

Tags: api, http, http-headers, yelp, get-request

Good evening everyone. I'm a beginner to API's in general and need some help with Yelp's Fusion API. I think there is some error with my Authorization Variable/Header. I run the request and get a 404 error. Can someone provide some clarity?

You can find more details on Yelp API on this link: https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/business_search

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search/';
header = {'Authorization':'Bearer MYLONGTOKENx'}

response = requests.get(url, headers = header)

print(response.status_code)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the example below, swap the key (xxxxxxxxxxxx) with your api key; I wrote this example for someone before I figure it will help you; in this example we'll make a secure call to Yelp's Business Search API and return back the JSON; parse it and use its values in a simple example; hope it helps!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <title>Ilan's Test</title>
   </head>
   <body>

   <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="results">

                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
   </div>

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script>
         var myurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=by-chloe&location=boston";

         $.ajax({
            url: myurl,
            headers: {
             'Authorization':'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
         },
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                // Grab the results from the API JSON return
                var totalresults = data.total;
                // If our results are greater than 0, continue
                if (totalresults > 0){
                    // Display a header on the page with the number of results
                    $('#results').append('<h5>We discovered ' + totalresults + ' results!</h5>');
                    // Itirate through the JSON array of 'businesses' which was returned by the API
                    $.each(data.businesses, function(i, item) {
                        // Store each business's object in a variable
                        var id = item.id;
                        var alias = item.alias;
                        var phone = item.display_phone;
                        var image = item.image_url;
                        var name = item.name;
                        var rating = item.rating;
                        var reviewcount = item.review_count;
                        var address = item.location.address1;
                        var city = item.location.city;
                        var state = item.location.state;
                        var zipcode = item.location.zip_code;
                        // Append our result into our page
                        $('#results').append('<div id="' + id + '" style="margin-top:50px;margin-bottom:50px;"><img src="' + image + '" style="width:200px;height:150px;"><br>We found <b>' + name + '</b> (' + alias + ')<br>Business ID: ' + id + '<br> Located at: ' + address + ' ' + city + ', ' + state + ' ' + zipcode + '<br>The phone number for this business is: ' + phone + '<br>This business has a rating of ' + rating + ' with ' + reviewcount + ' reviews.</div>');
                  });
                } else {
                    // If our results are 0; no businesses were returned by the JSON therefor we display on the page no results were found
                    $('#results').append('<h5>We discovered no results!</h5>');
                }
            }
         });      

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```