# Yelp API Authorization using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, http-headers, authorization, yelp

I am still learning to work with different APIs, and have been working with JavaScript and the Yelp API. I have tried using Ajax, as well as the code I have posted here, but I continue to get the error of:

"code": "TOKEN_MISSING",
    "description": "An access token must be supplied in order to use this endpoint."

I will continue to search through other posts, but if anyone could point out to me what I am doing incorrectly and how to fix it, I would really appreciate it?

```
var URL = 'https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?location=40515&term&categories=vet&limit=10';

var API_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

   var req = new Request(url, {
           method: 'GET',
           headers: new Headers({
             'Authorization: Bearer', API_KEY,
             'Content-Type': 'application/json'
           })
           mode: 'no-cors'
         });

        fetch (req)
          .then((response) => {
             if(response.ok){
             return response.json();
           }else{ssss
             throw new Error();
           }
         })
         .then((jsonData) => {
             console.log(jsonData);
           })
          .catch((err) => {
             console.log('ERROR: ', err.message);
           });
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to fix up:

```
'Authorization: Bearer', API_KEY,
```

to be something like:

```
'Authorization': `Bearer ${API_KEY}`,
```

or:

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + API_KEY,
```

And if this line isn't just redacted for posting here:

```
var API_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
```

then you would need to actually get an API key from yelp as `'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'` would not be a valid key

Comment: Thank you! This seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think an answer I posted before to a similar question with a full code sample may lead you in the right direction:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51461033/9525657

Have a look, it’s an easy and simple process of pulling from the service :)

Comment: Thank you for this information! I am able to get it to work now.

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a try!